# Image not showing when UpdatePanel triggers

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am currently developing a website using ASP.NET and C#. In this website I display 2 sets of Image Banners, the first one is filled with my C# code and stays still (does not change).

```
 <div class="divArticleCar">

    <div id="OwlDemo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="padding:25px;" runat="server">
    </div>

    <div class="customNavigation ">
        <a class="btn prev "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span><br/></a>
        <a class="btn next "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span><br/></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

The second uses a connection to an external API from an image Database. I have a text input and a button so when user searches for a key word, the second banner updates with new images. I'm using AJAX `<asp:UpdatePanel>` tag to update the image result.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel2" updatemode="Conditional">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="btnSearchImage" EventName="ServerClick" />
  </Triggers>
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="divArticleCar">
      <div id="OwlDemo2" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="padding:25px;" runat="server">
      </div>
    <div class="customNavigation CN2">
          <a class="btn prev2 ">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span>  <br>
            </a>
            <a class="btn next2 ">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span> <br>
            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The problem is when the Images in the ContentTemplate are updated. They are just not shown, the banner disappears. I have checked my background code, C# is getting the API results and it is adding the new images, they are just not visible. The Banners are managed with 2 Javascript files.

First: [carrusel.js](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0coa0730rippbft/carrusel.js?dl=0)

Second: [owlCarousel.js](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bt0vyhbt1n4mmqt/owlCarousel.js?dl=0)

Does someone know why the images are disappearing??

Comment: Irrespective of your particular stack, you still output `HTML` + `CSS` + `JS`. If you could provide a [mcve] of your problem, we could tell you what `CSS` rule or `JavaScript` function determines the current state of your elements and you could track it to its source and fix it or, alternatively, you could enforce a stronger rule to display your elements properly. Anything interesting in your browser's console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every javascript function that is called when the page is done loading needs to be triggered again when you use an `UpdatePanel`.

So lets say you have something like this somewhere to build the carousel:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    buildCarousel();
});
```

You need to add some code to make sure `buildCarousel()` is triggered again after partial postback.

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function () {
    buildCarousel();
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what happened, the script controlling the Carousel was not initializing on postback. Images were there but "displayed" property was set on NONE. Thanks